# Use preg_replace() to Isolate Number in Source Code

Tags: php, preg-replace, file-get-contents

I am trying to pick out a single value (in this instance, the value is 544007664) from the source code of a page that I am pulling of YouTube. Right now, the script that I have is successfully loading the source code from the YouTube page and removing the "<" and ">" symbols so that when I echo the source code, it displays as text and doesn't display the page itself. The two preg_replace() functions (here on lines 4 and 5) that pull out everything before and after the desired value are not doing what I expect them to do.

The only thing I can think of is that preg_replace() is refusing to read as a single string text that is in reality several dozens of individual lines.

```
<?php
$str = file_get_contents('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5XR7naZ_zZA');
$str = $str;
$str = preg_replace('~^(.)+(meta name="twitter:app:id:ipad" content=")~', '', $str);
$str = preg_replace('~(" meta name="twitter:app:url:iphone")+(.)$~', '', $str);
$str = preg_replace('~<~', '', $str);
$str = preg_replace('~>~', '', $str);
echo $str;
?>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You probably wanted to use `preg_match`. Try pattern [like this](https://regex101.com/r/qI2nO3/2): `$pattern = '/<meta\b(?=[^>]+?twitter:app:id:iphone)[^>]+?\bcontent\s*=\s*"([^"]+)"/i';`. In result `$out[1]` holds your match of first parenthesized group. Do same for `twitter:app:url:iphone`. [See demo at eval.in](https://eval.in/505852) or use `preg_match_all` with single regex [like this demo](https://eval.in/505856).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're on the right track with this one, but are overthinking it a bit.

Here's a simple snippet that you can use to get the numbers:

```
$str = file_get_contents('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5XR7naZ_zZA');

$app_store_id = preg_replace('~.*?<meta property="al:ios:app_store_id" content="(\d+)">.*~si', '$1', $str); 

print $app_store_id;
```

This outputs:

```
544007664
```

Here is an explanation of the regex:

- `.*?` - Match any character `.`, any number of times `*`, until it hits the next portion of the regex string `?`.  The next part is the specific `<meta ...` tag we are looking for.
- `<meta property="al:ios:app_store_id" content="` - This just locates the meta tag with the "app_store_id" in it.
- `(\d+)` - This is grabbing at least one `+` digit `\d`.  We put it in parenthesis because then it will be assigned to `$1`.  We will use the value of `$1` to replace the contents of the string.  (So we are replacing the entire web page with only the number that we found.)
- `">` - Finishing off the meta tag.
- `.*` - Match any character `.`, any number of times `*` after the meta tag.

---

Note that I am using the `s` flag after my expression to make newlines count as a character.  This will effectively let you search across multiple lines.  Often, the `s` flag is paired with the `m` flag, although in this case it wasn't necessary.

Here is a link to a page listing the different flags you can use in PHP.

http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php